How to find basis of vector fields?
I'm figuring out definition of vector fields over a manifold as differentiations of algebra $C^\infty(M)$ of functions on $M$. How can we find their basis starting from this very definition? I know, in some chart $(U, \varphi)$, it must be some
$$X|_U = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$
but how to obtain it?
All we know $X$ is some differentiation i.e.
$$X(fg)=Xf\cdot g+f\cdot Xg$$
and that's it.
EDIT: I'm asking, of course, about a basis in some chart $(U, \varphi)$. I editted the question.

What do you mean "how to obtain it"? As with a basis in a vector space you just choose one. You can extend any chosen basis of the tangent space at a point into vector fields locally although you can't guarantee globally that these vector spaces are non-vanishing let alone form a basis as @Lieven's answer mentions

For sake of simplicity let us explain in dimension 2, with two coordinate $(x,y)$, so in an open set of $\bf R^2$.
Let $X$ be a derivation, i.e. an operator on $C^{\infty}$ such that $X(f.g)=fX(g)+gX(f)$, $X(\lambda f+g)=\lambda X.f+X.g$. Let $a$ the function $X.x$, $b$ the function $X.y$ we want to show $X= a.{\partial \over \partial x}+ b.{\partial \over \partial y}$.
Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be a point, and write
$f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)+(x-x_0) A(x,y)+(y-y_0)B(x,y)$, with $A,B$ of class $C^{\infty}$. (Hadamard lemma)
then $(X.f)(x_0,y_0)= [X.f(x_0,y_0)](x_0,y_0) +A(x_0,y_0)[ X. (x-x_0)](x_0,y_0) +B(x_0,y_0)[ X. (x-x_0)](x_0,y_0)$.
We first note that $X.c=0$ if $c$ is a constant function : indeed $X.c=cX.1=c X. 1^2=2cX.1=2. X.c$, so the first term is $0$.
Remark  that $A(x_0,y_0)={\partial \over \partial x} f(x_0,y_0)$,  $B(x_0,y_0)={\partial \over \partial y} f(x_0,y_0)$, and that $X(x-x_0)= X.x=a$, $X(y-y_0)= X.y=b$.
Using linearity, we get
$(X.f)(x_0,y_0)=(a.{\partial \over \partial x}+ b.{\partial \over \partial y}) f (x_0,y_0)$.
This identity is true at every point whence the result.

Thank you very much! Seems it's exactly what I was looking for. :D

On the domain of an individual coordinate chart the vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ ($i=1,\ldots,n$) form a basis in every fibre; but in a different coordinate system, on the intersection of two charts, these vectors will in general be linear combinations of the basis vectors of the other chart. The existence of a global basis of vector fields on a manifold is not guaranteed and depends on the global topology of the manifold.
As a commenter pointed out, the $2$-sphere cannot have a global nonzero vector field, so no single vector field can be part of a basis everywhere.

Famously, the 2-sphere doesn't have a basis. Any continuous vector field is zero somewhere, so given a candidate basis with 2 fields there will be points where the span is one-dimensional, and if you have 3 fields there is bound to be a lot of linear dependence going on.
